# H.264 Video format (YUV420p vs YUV420sp)

Tags: video, h.264

I'm doing a video streaming project.
The standard only mentions using the following format for video:

The terminal shall support H.264 video codecs by default using the H.264 
- frame rate of 25 frames / sec
- CIF (352 * 288) format
- payload type (payload_type): 98
- timestamp frequency (kHz): 90

By default my Android device packs the data in YUV420SP format.
When the video goes thru, it comes up with a green tint and a slight distortion.

Probing further it seems that I should have used the YUV420P format instead.

Can somebody help educate me on why H264 itself does not define the actual data format to use? Doesn't this leave it open to developer interpretation instead? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to graphics stack exchange: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

H.264 is the specification for "coding of moving video".
The standard describes the syntax of the (compressed) bitstream.

H.264 does not describe a vendor specific encoder input format.
It is common practice to leave the encoder specification out or wide open.

Answer (score 1):

Codecs typically will support different pixel formats - YUV is a pixel format space, like RGB - a way of encoding the colour of a pixel.

Codecs actually have many different parameters that can be set - to try help usage they generally define profiles which provide values for key parameters to us. For example, HEVC codec (h.265) has many different profiles.

Your point is essentially correct - it is possible to have a device support h.264, but not support the particular parameters you select.

Comment: YUV or RGB are not color spaces - they are pixel formats. Rec. 601, 709 and 2020 are color spaces.